# How to extract numbers from a string

Tags: java, regex

```
String a = "sin(23)+cos(4)+2!+3!+44!";
a.replaceAll("\D"); //Not working it is only extracting Digits
```

I want to extract the numbers which are with `!` only (example `2` and `3`), then have to save it in a `int[]` and have to again paste those numbers at the place where `2!` and `3!` exist.

Comment: Note: `replaceAall` returns a **new** String, it doesn't modify the current object.

Comment: If you are trying to build calculator then this is wrong approach. What if you will have to calculate `((1+2)!+3)!`?

Comment: I don't get this `have to again paste those numbers at the place where 2! and 3! exist.`. Where do you want to paste them ? What's the expected output ? And what about `44!` ?

Comment: @Pshemo i am using JEP library for parsing and evaluating expressions it does not have factorial method.. and so i created it but the problem is my method factorial(int) in it so i want those values which are with "!" in my string

Comment: @HamZa back in my string at the place of 2! and 3!

Comment: @user3044181 So basically you want to match them and put them in an array and do nothing with the input (variable `a` in this case) ? I think you should just check out the manual or fire some queries to your favorite search engine and use `\\d+(?=!)` as your pattern. Note that in Java you need to escape the backslash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use regular expression to find what you want:

```
String a = "sin(23)+cos(4)+2!+3!+44!";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+!"); //import java.util.regex.Pattern
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(a);       //import java.util.regex.Matcher
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
    System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end() + " -> ");
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

**Output:**

```
Start index: 15 End index: 17 -> 2!
Start index: 18 End index: 20 -> 3!
Start index: 21 End index: 24 -> 44!
```

---

**Further improvement:**

With the following, you can cast the `matcher.group(1)` return value directly using `Integer.parseInt()`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)!");
...
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

**Output:**

```
Start index: 15 End index: 17 -> 2
Start index: 18 End index: 20 -> 3
Start index: 21 End index: 24 -> 44
```

---

Can you figure out the rest? You could use the index values to replace the matches in the original string, but **be sure** to start from the last one.

Answer (score 5):

First thing: Strings are [immutable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html). You code you tried should be more like

```
a = a.replaceAll("\\D","");
```

Second, if you are sure that you will not have more complext expressions like `((1+2)!+3)!` then you can use `appendReplacement` and `appendTail` methods from Matcher class.

```
String a = "sin(23)+cos(4)+2!+3!+44!";

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)!");
Matcher m = p.matcher(a);
while(m.find()){
    String number = m.group(1);//only part in parenthesis, without "!"
    m.appendReplacement(sb, calculatePower(m.group(number )));
}
m.appendTail(sb);
a = sb.toString();
```

Comment: This actually doesn't answer the question (something about `!` and `int[]` array)