# How to extract numbers from a string using regex?

Tags: java, regex

```
String a = "sin(23)+cos(4)+2!+3!+44!";
a.replaceAll("(\d+!)","");


Current Output = sin(23),+,cos(4),+,+,+
```

I want result  2!,3!,44!

Please help

Comment: Um, what's the difference between this and [that previous question of yours?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21478873/1578604)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String a = "sin(23)+cos(4)+2!+3!+44!";
    Pattern number = Pattern.compile("\\d+!");
    Matcher matcher = number.matcher(a);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Backslash must be escaped by doubling it and ! maybe needs escape also as it has special meaning in some context, so use

```
 \\d+\\!
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need:

```
\+(\d+!)
```

It matches 2! and 3! and 44!

[See it in action](http://regex101.com/r/uS7fM5)

Comment: I want to match all other characters except 2!, 3! and 44!